Evaluating Complex Series Convergence Radius by Hadamard's Theorem
Zorich's Mathematical Analysis Page 286:

a) Making the formal substitution $z-a=(z-z_0)+(z_0-a)$ in the power series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}A_n(z-a)^n$ and gathering like terms, obtain a series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n(z-z_0)^n$ and expressions for its oefficients in terms of $A_k$ and $(z_0-a)^k,k=0,1,2,\cdots$

b) Verify that if the original series converges in the disk $|z-a|
<R$ and $|z_0-a|=r<R$ then the series defining $C_n,n=0,1,\cdots,$ converges absolutely and the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n(z-z_0)^n$ converges to $|z-z_0|<R-r$.
c) Show that if $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty A_n(z-a)^n$ in the disk $|z-a|<R$ and $|z_0-a|<R$, then in the disk $|z-z_0|<R-|z_0-a|$ the function $f$ admits the representation $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n(z-z_0)^n$
I have managed to solve part $a)$, but have no idea for part $b)$.
My Attempt for part a)
$$I=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}A_n(z-a)^n$$
$$=\sum_{n=0}^\infty A_n[(z-z_0)+(z_0-a)]^n$$
$$=\sum_{n=0}^\infty A_n\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} (z_0-a)^{n-k}(z-z_0)^k$$
$$=\sum_{n=0}^\infty A_n\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{n}{k} (z_0-a)^{n-k}(z-z_0)^k$$
$$=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^\infty A_n \binom {n}{k} (z_0-a)^{n-k}(z-z_0)^k$$
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{n=k}^\infty A_n\binom {n}{k} (z_0-a)^{n-k}(z-z_0)^k$$
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left( \sum_{n=k}^\infty A_n\binom {n}{k} (z_0-a)^{n-k}\right)(z-z_0)^k$$
Which gives us $C_k= \sum_{n=k}^\infty A_n\binom {n}{k} (z_0-a)^{n-k}$
My Partial Attempt for part b)
We know by Hadamard Theorem that $\overline{\lim_{n\to\infty}}\sqrt[n]{|A_n|}=\frac 1 R$, and we are now to prove that $\overline{\lim_{k\to\infty}}\sqrt[k]{|c_k|}=\frac{1}{R-r}.$
But I have failed to prove this limit equality. Could you help me?

The function $f(z)$ is analytic in $D={z,:,|z-a|<R}.$ Hence it can be represented by the Taylor series at $z_0,$ so that ${z,:, |z-z_0|<r}\subset D.$ This gives the condition $r<R-|z_0-a|.$ However it is possible to solve b) with no use of complex analysis thoerym

We have $$ |C_k|\le \sum_{k=n}^\infty |A_n|{n\choose k}|z_0-a|^n$$ hence $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty |C_k||z-z_0|^k\le  \sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{k=n}^\infty |A_n|{n\choose k}|z_0-a|^n |z-z_0|^k\\ =
\sum_{n=0}^\infty |A_n|(|z_0-a|+|z-z_0|)^n$$ The last series is convergent when $|z_0-a|+|z-z_0|<R.$ In such case the series  $\sum_{k=0}^\infty C_k(z-z_0)^k$ is absolutely convergent, hence convergent.
Remark $\mathbf{1}$The radius of convergence of the series  $\sum_{k=0}^\infty C_k(z-z_0)^k$ can be larger than $R-|z_0-a|.$ For example consider $f(z)={1\over 1+z}$ and $a=0.$ Then $R=1.$ For $z_0={1\over 2}$ we have $$f(z) ={1\over {3\over 2}+(z-{1\over 2})}$$ The radius of convergence is equal $3/2.$
Remark $\mathbf{2}$ Instead of the Cauchy-Hadamard formula the following is often more handy $$R=\sup \{|x-a|\,:\, a_n(x-a)^n\to 0\}$$
